# Struggling with making a for each loop using a object I made

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

So I have an array of an object I made called Item, and I'd like to use a for each loop to go through this array.

```
private ArrayList carriedItems;
  /**
 * this private helper method checks the ArrayList for the requested Item name.  If found, return the Item.  
 * If not found, return null.
 * @param the name of the item
 * @return the item object
 */ 
public Item cherForItem(String name){
    for(Item i: carriedItems)
        if(name.compareTo(i.getName())==0)
            return i;
    return null;
}
```

when I compile I get an incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Item. I know this means it's expecting an Item object, but I thought the last word in a for each loop was the array of things you were going through? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As brso05 pointed out, you have to specify the datatype of the ArrayList contents using the template brackets (otherwise the contents are cast as Java.Lang.Object)

Specify the type when you declare the ArrayList variable carriedItems, and you should be fine:

```
private ArrayList<Item> carriedItems;
  /**
 * this private helper method checks the ArrayList for the requested Item name.  If found, return the Item.  
 * If not found, return null.
 * @param the name of the item
 * @return the item object
 */ 
public Item cherForItem(String name){
    for(Item i: carriedItems)
        if(name.compareTo(i.getName())==0)
            return i;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should define your arraylist like this:

```
private ArrayList<Item> carriedItems;
```

You didn't specify the type of data your arraylist will be holding...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Generics.

```
private ArrayList<Item> carriedItems;

public Item getItem(){
// your code
}
```

Generics are made for getting rid of such problems.